# VBA - Is the IsDate(expression) function broken or am I being an idiot?

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I might be completely missing something blatantly obvious or just generally being stupid but the IsDate() function in VBA won't return anything other than "Compile error - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

I am trying to use it for what is actually quite a basic user input verification procedure in a larger program.

I have made a smaller subroutine to experiment with it and try and work out what I am doing wrong but turning up nothing.
I have compared my code to the official brief on the function at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function even copying and pasting their code and running it but its still causing this error.

```
Sub IsDate()

Dim datastart As String
Dim v As Boolean

datastart = "22/03/2023"
'datastart = "222/03//2023"

MsgBox datastart
v = IsDate(datastart)
MsgBox ver

End Sub
```

[I get this same error every time no matter how I use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hmal.png)#

Am I missing something?

Any and all help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you use `VBA.IsDate(yourStringDate)`?

Comment: The name of your Sub clashes ... change the name of your Sub

Comment: `IsDate` is a reserved VBA word...

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, your Sub is called `IsDate`. You've basically confused yourself/Excel.

Rename your sub and it should solve the issue. Also, you want to output `v`, not `ver`.

```
Sub CheckDate()

    Dim datastart As String
    Dim v As Boolean
    
    datastart = "22/03/2023"
    
    MsgBox datastart
    v = IsDate(datastart)
    MsgBox v

End Sub
```

Comment: I initially made the subroutine and called it as such after I had the problem occurring in a larger program. I can't explain why but after changing it on the smaller test subroutine it's now working.

Strange but I'll take it. 

Thank you kindly sir!

Answer (score 0):

Just to further this for anyone else making the same silly mistake as I have:

I originally was using the function wrong, I assumed it to be used in the format `x = expression.IsDate` rather than `x = IsDate(expression)`.

Due to this I reverted to using a smaller subroutine to play around with it and work out what I was doing wrong, which as CLR pointed out above I named `IsDate()` causing it to clash with excel's built in function I was trying to use.

After realizing I was using the function wrong I changed it to the proper format, i.e. `IsDate(expression)` and then got the error mentioned above.

Rather stupid of me but hopefully anyone viewing this post in the future can learn from it and avoid making the same mistake.